# ExpectedConditions class throws numerous errors when running selenium test

Tags: java, selenium

My test used to run fine prior to February 20th. Starting from the morning of this day I see numerous errors in a console. They look like:

```
лют. 21, 2017 2:38:19 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //a[@href='/#/activities']//span)
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //a[@href='/#/activities']//span
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.1.0', revision: 'b94c902', time: '2017-02-16 12:21:31 -0800'
System info: host: 'SALSALABS5', ip: '192.168.15.114', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.lambda$findElement$0(ExpectedConditions.java:896)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:895)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$000(ExpectedConditions.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$6.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:234)
    at com.vitalii.vitaliiFramework2.helpers.Waiters.fluentWaitIgnoringNoSuchElementExceptionAndElementNotVisibleException(Waiters.java:85)
    at com.vitalii.vitaliiFramework2.pages.DashboardPage.goToActivitiesPage(DashboardPage.java:20)
    at com.vitalii.vitaliiFramework2.tests.LoginPageTestsWD.doSuccessfulLoginTest(LoginPageTestsWD.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Obviously this is because of ExpectedConditions class.

Project is complied successfully and my IDE does not show any errors in any class. The issue is only observed during tests' run-time and always causes test to fail at some point.

I did not update browser OR my pom.xml. It was fine before weekend and fails now.

Browser - FF 47.0
Selenium - 3.1.0

Example of my code that uses ExpectedConditions class is:

```
public void fluentWaitIgnoringNoSuchElementExceptionAndElementNotVisibleException(final String locator){
        long waitingTime = 30; 
        long pollingInterval = 500;
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(waitingTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(pollingInterval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                .ignoring(ElementNotVisibleException.class)
                .withMessage("Fluent wait of " + waitingTime + " seconds with " + pollingInterval + " milliseconds polling interval was unable to locate element with locator " + locator);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(locator)));
    }
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the `ExpectedConditions` uses in your code?

Comment: @Guy I added a code to the description. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Congratulation! You just caught a bug! ;)

I think there is nothing wrong with ExpectedConditions, but more likely there are some changes in the html of the page.

I would check the test case manually on FF to see what have changed.

Comment: its 100% not about application. I use FluentWaits in my test and tests keep running up to some point. In console aforementioned errors is being thrown continuously (just every second) during run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix for this was downgrading selenium version from 3.1.0 to 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

according to the changelog they "Remove deprecated `FluentWait.until(Predicate<?>)` method. This
  should make lambdas work properly with Wait instances now."

-changes in 3.1.0
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG